# How to solve probability for reaching final state in the following question?

Tags: probability

I recently received this question in an online test. I had 2 minutes to give an answer. The methods that I was thinking of would take much longer than 2 minutes. Is there a trick that I am missing to solve this quickly? The question is as follows:

There is a biased dice that has 30% chance of landing on an even number and 70% chance on an odd. You start with \$10 and bet \$1 on the dice at a time. If it lands on even number, then you win \$1 (in addition to getting back the \$1 that you bet), and if it lands on odd then you lose the dollar that you bet. You win the game when you have \$20 and lose when you have 0. What is the probability that you win?

Comment: I think more context is needed.  Can you use a computer?  There's a simple closed formula for the general Gambler's ruin problem...can you use that?  To do it from scratch with pencil and paper in two minutes seems hard.

Comment: It looks like the gambler has no choice.  even=win, odd=lose.  Problem needs restating.

Comment: Please do not deface your questions

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use conditional probability. Let N denote the throw on which the game ends. We know N will be even and at least 10, so:
$$P(win) = P(win |N=10)P(N=10) + P(win|N=12)P(N=12)  +...$$

But $P(win|N=k)= \frac {.3^{10}}{.3^{10}+.7^{10}}$ for all even k, so that can be factored out. And the $P(N=k)$ terms sum to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Say you're at a winning position. If you flipped every loss with a win, and vice versa, you would be at a losing position, meaning you have $10$ more losses ($70\%$ chance each) and $10$ less wins ($30\%$ chance each). So the probability of losing is $\left(\frac{70\%}{30\%}\right)^{10}$ that of winning. We also know they sum to one. Thus, the probability of winning is $$\frac{1}{\left(\frac{7}{3}\right)^{10}+1} = \frac{3^{10}}{3^{10}+7^{10}}$$